# Select urls from Typo3 Database via Typoscript query

Tags: database, typoscript, typo3-8.x

First my goal: I want to create a list with links to internal pages. This list has to be ordered by creation date (crdate in the DB)

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
99 = CONTENT
99.table = pages
99.select {
    pidInList = root,-1
    selectFields = url
    orderBy = crdate
}
```

Sadly, this returns nothing.
For debugging I played with the different properties.
With

```
99 = CONTENT
99.table = tt_content
99.select {
    pidInList = 1
    orderBy = crdate
}
```

I cloned my rootpage. I got all records from it.
So I know that all page records should be stored in the Pages table with the url.

What am I doing wrong here?

Additional information: Typo3 8.7, no the default backend elements are not working for me, yes I have to do it in typoscript

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `url` in the `pages` record does not hold the url from that page in general.
It is used only for pages of type `external URL`, so the internal link to this page can be forwarded to that url.

If you want a link list of all your pages you need to create a link to these pages:

```
99 = CONTENT
99 {
   table = pages
   select {
      // your selection here
   }

   renderObj = TEXT
   renderObj {
      typolink {
         parameter.field = uid
      }
   }
}
```

This will give you a list (if wrapping the `renderObj` with `<li>|</li>`) of complete links with page title as link text.

If you want only urls you can add:

```
typolink {
   returnLast = url
}
```

Without wrapping it will be a long string without separation.

---

EDIT:

```
99 = CONTENT
99 {
   table = pages
   select {
      pidInList = 69
      orderBy = crdate desc
   }
   wrap = <ul>|</ul>

   renderObj = TEXT
   renderObj {
      wrap = <li>|</li>
      typolink {
         parameter.field = uid
      }
      if.isFalse.cObject = CONTENT
      if.isFalse.cObject {
         table = pages
         select {
            // this 'uid' is from context of current pages record we have selected above
            pidInList.field = uid
            // this 'uid' is the field from the records we are selecting here
            selectFields = uid
         }

         renderObj = TEXT
         // this 'uid' is the selected field above 
         // a field in the pages record of the subquery to decide if there are child pages
         renderObj.field = uid
         # renderObj.wrap = |,
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can "walk down" my pagetree and select only the pages, that don't have children?

Comment: I would solve that with a menu. there you get the info if a page has subpages easily ('NO', 'IFSUB'). Don't forget to expand all levels with `expAll = 1`. Alternative use a menu processor and build it in fluid. (of course the sorting is the structure of the pages and not ordered by `crdate`)

Comment: of course you can build a condition if a page has subpages with a query inside the `renderObj`. but there is no direct information in a `pages`record about subpages.

Comment: I already tried the sultion with the menu but as you said, you can not order it by crdate. I have no experience with custom queries :/ How are these working?

Comment: as you already did: using a `CONTENT` object. the problem is the correct usage in a wrap in the `renderObj`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227953/discussion-between-hofferik-johnerinst-and-bernd-wilke-).